# Largura/tamanho botões Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Olá, a todos! Como eu poderia colocar todos os botões de um grupo de botões Bootstrap do mesma largura independente do conteúdo e ainda continuar responsivo. Por exemplo eu tenho um grupo de botões: A B NA, o botão A  e B tem o mesmo tamanho, já o NA é maior. Eu gostaria que todos ficassem do mesmo tamanho. Agradeço

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo certo. Acredito que seja o que vc está procurando

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**

Você vai precisar criar um estilo customizado e incluir como ultimo na sequência. No exemplo abaixo criei os estilos pequeno e médio. Observe que inclui por ultimo na sequência de imports.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .pequeno {
                width: 20%;
            }

            .medio {
                width: 50%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Button Styles</h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pequeno">Default</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pequeno">Primary</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success medio">Success</button>     
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

Desculpa, interpretei errado tua pergunta. Na verdade você quer o mesmo tamanho independente do conteúdo certo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <style>
                .mesmo-tamanho {
                    width: 15%;
                    white-space: normal;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Button Styles</h2>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Default Default</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mesmo-tamanho">Primary Primary Primary Primary</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mesmo-tamanho">Success Success Success</button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: O problema é que a altura do botão bootstrap permanece e a fonte (botão) fica desalinhada, não centraliza e sai para a direita mesmo colocando a fonte responsiva.

Comment: Não entendi, poderia ser mais especifico pf?

Comment: Se visualizarmos em uma tela menor, o botão bootstrap diminui de largura mas não de altura. O conteúdo do botão não fica centralizado. O texto do botão fica mais a direita e sai do interior do botão.